# what is the purpose of $state.includes in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, angularjs-ng-include

I'm new in angularjs, I've little confuse between **ng-include** and **$state.includes**. Can anyone please suggest me why we using the $state.includes instead of ng-include directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine you have a parent menu with some child menus. For each child menu you have something like this for adding active class:

```
ui-sref-active="active"
```

But you also need to add active class for parent menu when you navigate to **each of** the child states.Then you can use `ui-router` includes.

```
<li ng-class="{ active: state.includes('parentState') }">
```

**Note:** You must add this to your controller:

```
$scope.state = $state;
```

About ng-include, it doesn't relate to $state.include. It compiles external html into the directive.

Answer (score 1):

They are both way seperate things. Like Java and JavaScript? :-)

- [`$state.includes`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params) is a way to see if the current state is or is child of the provided state while using [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

  > ## `$state.includes(stateName [, params])`
  >
  > Returns **Boolean**
  >
  > A method to determine if the current active state is equal to or is the child of the state `stateName`. If any `params` are passed then they will be tested for a match as well. Not all the parameters need to be passed, just the ones you'd like to test for equality.
- Where as, [**`ng-include`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) is a AngularJS directive to fetch, compile and include an external HTML fragment.

---

You should probably try to read about them on the Internet before asking about it though!